# Geonetwork catalog dataset statistics

Tags: statistics, ogc, geonetwork, csw

I want to get some statistics about my geonetwork catalog. Things I would like to know are

- total dataset count
- dataset count for different format types (e.g. CSV, WMS, etc.)
- dataset count that is valid for a specific geographic region

The best thing I could think of so far, is to query the catalog with the GetRecords operation, optionally filtered to restrict feature count.

Then it would be neccessary to parse the response and count the occurrence of e.g. individual identifiers.

This would be possible but doesn't sound too nice, as I assume there should be some better solution already available for this, because it sounds like a must have for a geodata catalogue.

Does anyone know of a better solution to this, by means of an OGC request to csw or a geonetwork specific solution?

**UPDATE:**

Just found, there is a built-in solution to this in the catalog UI as described [here](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/#analyze-information). Thats actually what I need, but I would like to query it from the API to show it in tabular format.

Answer (score 2):

Found one possible solution, which is to use this request (grabbed it out of the firebug console when loading the catalog startpage):

```
https://catalog-url/geonetwork/srv/eng/qi?_content_type=json&summaryOnly=true
```

It contains the useful sections, amongst others

- @count
- formats
- serviceTypes

which I think I can build something out of at least.

Comment: Yes, that would be the "formal" way to do it. You can create your own summary types defining them on config-summary.xml and request this q service with the summary parameter to get the type of facets you need.

Comment: @Délawen That sounds good, I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :) Is there an official API in the mean time? The only one I found was `GET /srv/resources/records`, which is unbearably slow..